# Static field initiation in to unmodifiable set

Tags: java, findbugs

I have a static field which is initialized by a config property in the static block. My code will run for Fingbugs warning which encounters a warning like mentioned below.

> Field is a mutable collection
>   A mutable collection instance is assigned to a final static field, thus can be changed by malicious code or by accident from another package. Consider wrapping this field into Collections.unmodifiableSet/List/Map/etc. to avoid this vulnerability.

```
Class A{
private static String uri;

static{
    uri= Properties.getpropery("SOME_PROPERTY"); /// Here i am getting the Findbugs warning 
} 

}
```

How can I make as Unmodified Set and pass this as String literal in later stages?

Comment: Do you still have the error when you mark the field as final?

Comment: Did you try `private static final URI = Properties.getProperty ()`. ? It's should works

Comment: @ÉricRoberge, Still seeing the same issue after this change

Comment: Do you use a static collection anywhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Findbugs. Try marking the field as ***private*** for now, perhaps that helps to solve it. If this does not help fixing it, my gut feeling of it being a bug just got a bit bigger.

As you can tell the exception is somewhat off because it's not a Collection and no changes can be made outside this class because it has the `private` access modifier and it is a String which are immutable by nature in Java.

Let's take a look at this example;

```
    public class Class1 {

        private static String STRING_VALUE = "I'm secure!";
        private static List<String> COLLECTION = Arrays.asList("I'm Secure!");

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Class2.changeStatic(STRING_VALUE);
            System.out.println(STRING_VALUE); // I'm secure!

            Class2.changeStatic(COLLECTION);
            System.out.println(COLLECTION.get(0)); // I'm unsecure!
        }
    }

   public class Class2 {

        public static void changeStatic(String secureString) {
            secureString = "I'm unsecure!";
        }

        public static void changeStatic(List<String> unsecureList) {
            unsecureList.set(0, "I'm unsecure!");
        }
    }
```

As you can see, there is no way of changing the string value of Class1 outside of the class itself. In the case of a collection this is possible because the elements are held in a mutable container.

Because changing the elements in the Collection is possible outside the class/package they suggest wrapping it in an unmodifiable Collection which do not delegate the modifications to the wrapped list but instead throw an Exception:

```
    public class Class1 {

        private static List<String> COLLECTION = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("I'm Secure!"));

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Class2.changeStatic(COLLECTION);
        }
    }

   public class Class2 {

        public static void changeStatic(List<String> unsecureList) {
            unsecureList.set(0, "I'm unsecure!"); // throws a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not a bug in Findbugs.

Comment: @LewBloch How do you know this for sure? Can you elaborate? Where is the security risk that I'm clearly missing?

Comment: Findbugs as been around for over a decade. It's never the tool, to a second order of approximation. The risk is that the collection would be modified by a client and that the programmer might misunderstand `final`. The OP talks about a `Set` and the code they posted is uncompilable and doesn't show a `Set`. I conclude that the posted code is not the code Findbugs analyzed. The message is legitimate if the OP did have a `Set` in the actual code that they didn't show us.

Comment: Well yes, there is always the possibility that he misinterpreted the location of the warning. We cannot know for sure. And every piece of software, regardless how old, can contain certain quirks. I don't use Findbugs so unfortunately I cannot validate the behaviour specified.